# How do I use isomap from sklearn for dimensionalty reduction of high-dimensional space

Tags: machine-learning, multidimensional-array, scikit-learn

I need example on how to use isomap from sklearn for dimensionalty reduction of high-dimensional space defined in numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Load digits sample dataset from sklearn:**

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
digits = load_digits()
print(digits.images.shape) # Result: (1797, 8, 8). 1797 images, 8x8 dimensions
print(digits.data.shape)   # Result: (1797, 64)
```

So we have data with 64 dimensions.

**Using isomap from sklearn to reduce dimensionalty on 2**

```
from sklearn.manifold import Isomap
iso = Isomap(n_components=2)
iso.fit(digits.data)
data_projected = iso.transform(digits.data)
data_projected.shape  # Result: (1797, 2)
```

**Projected data is now two-dimensional. We can plot this data to visualize it:**

```
plt.scatter(data_projected[:, 0], data_projected[:, 1], c=digits.target,
            edgecolor='none', alpha=0.5,
            cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('spectral', 10))
plt.colorbar(label='digit label', ticks=range(10))
plt.clim(-0.5, 9.5);
```

[image]